# Is there any way to give gradient color to normal color property in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, bar-chart, linear-gradients, fl-chart

I am using Bar Chart of fl_chart plugin. I want to give gradient color to bar graph. Below is the line where I want give color.

```
BarChartRodData(y: 12, color: Color(0xFF639ed1),width: 12)
```

But it is not possible to set gradient color to the ##color## property unless it is colors.

Is there any way to set gradient color to color property?? Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

If you pass just one color, the solid color will be used, or if you pass more than one color, we use gradient mode to draw. then the [gradientFrom](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/documentation/fl_chart/latest/fl_chart/BarAreaData/gradientFrom.html), [gradientTo](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/documentation/fl_chart/latest/fl_chart/BarAreaData/gradientTo.html) and [gradientColorStops](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/documentation/fl_chart/latest/fl_chart/BarAreaData/gradientColorStops.html)

For an example ,

```
final List<Color> color = <Color>[];
        color.add(Colors.blue[50]);
        color.add(Colors.blue[100]);
        color.add(Colors.blue);


 final List<double> stops = <double>[];
    stops.add(0.0);
    stops.add(0.5);
    stops.add(1.0);
```

Please refer https://pub.dev/documentation/fl_chart/latest/fl_chart/BarChartRodData-class.html for BarChartRodData class variables

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

In my case i have only properties like 
  double y,
    Color color,
    List<Color> colors,
    double width,
    BorderRadius borderRadius,
    BackgroundBarChartRodData backDrawRodData,
    List<BarChartRodStackItem> rodStackItems,

So i cant only use solid color.

I have used fl_charts  plugin.